# type 'Query' is not a subtype of type 'CollectionReference'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to sort my data by date_posted but i am getting 'type 'Query' is not a subtype of type 'CollectionReference'.' I have tried searching for the solutions but all in vain!
My code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:kopala_dictionary/models/words.dart';

class DatabaseService {
  //cloud databse colection

  final CollectionReference wordsCollection =
      Firestore.instance.collection('words').orderBy('date_posted');

  Future insertData(String word, String english_translation,
      String bemba_translation, String user_id, DateTime date_posted) async {
    return await wordsCollection.document().setData({
      'word': word,
      'english_translation': english_translation,
      'bemba_translation': bemba_translation,
      'user_id': user_id,
      'date_posted': date_posted
    });
  }

  //words list from snappshots

  List<Words> _wordsFromSnapShots(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return Words(
        word: doc.data['word'],
        englishTranslation: doc.data['english_translation'],
        bembaTranslation: doc.data['bemba_translation'],
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  //Stream snapshots

  Stream<List<Words>> get words {
    return wordsCollection.snapshots().map(_wordsFromSnapShots);
  }
}
```

When i change it to:

```
final CollectionReference wordsCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('words').orderBy('date_posted');
```

Am getting 'type 'Query' is not a subtype of type 'CollectionReference''

Answer (score 3):

Change this

```
 final CollectionReference wordsCollection =
  Firestore.instance.collection('words').orderBy('date_posted');
```

into this

```
    final Query wordsCollection =
  Firestore.instance.collection('words').orderBy('date_posted');
```

Comment: I have tried but now it's bringing this error 'type 'Query' is not a subtype of type 'CollectionReference''

Answer (score 2):

CollectionReference is a subclass of Query.  You can assign a CollectionReference to a Query, but not the other way around.  You will have to restructure your code more like this:

```
  // This refers to just the collection "words", no implied ordering
  final CollectionReference wordsCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('words');

  Stream<List<Words>> get words {
    // This forces an ordering on the documents in the collection
    return wordsCollection.orderBy('date_posted').snapshots().map(_wordsFromSnapShots);
  }
```

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, it's customary on Stack Overflow to upvote the answer and mark it is correct using the buttons to the left of the answer.